# URLLoader requests data format to be Text but it gets Binary issue?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a URLLoader which normally requesting the data to be in Text format, anyway on a specific conditions it might gets a Binary as result, which is actually just 1 integer number in binary format. Anyway the conversation :

```
var ba : ByteArray = ( e.currentTarget as URLLoader ).data; // failing on this row.
var r : int = ba.readInt();
```

doesnt passing anymore since the result data is in text forma due the request header...

- How to convert the result data into integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you need to change

```
urlLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY
```

But before you send a request. After, there's no point doing that.

**EDIT**

To read text into a binary (ByteArray)

```
var ba:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
ba.writeUTFBytes(( e.currentTarget as URLLoader ).data);
ba.position=0;
var myInteger:int=ba.readInt();
```

Comment: the issue that i am not sending it as BINARY request, but TEXT, anyway in very specific case the server will return a binary data to handle, and then the headbanging starts :|

Comment: yes. actually i have tried this way already but the number which comes out is not the one which is really sent from the server.. :|

Answer (score 3):

if You are sure that You recive int there , type :

```
var value:int= int(( e.currentTarget as URLLoader ).data);
```

Same thing You can do if You get string or XML .

But if You like to recive data as ByteArray , You should type before load on URLLoader line :

```
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
urlloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
```

than Your data will be bytearray.

Comment: the dataFormat can be switched after the data is received ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.writeInt(0x00DDAA99);   //create my byte array with int 14527129
    bytes.position = 0;           //move the postion to the start
    var newInt:int = bytes.readInt();  //read the bytes from starting position
    trace("new num: "+newInt);    //print out the number
}
```

Basic reading and writing an integer to byte array

Comment: :|this is different from my case. I got a binary data which actually is missrepresented as a text. and i need to transform it back into binary data and probably then read the integer out of it.